# Limiting database output in AngularJS when using $http and get()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I get data from the database using the `$http` service and `get()` method. The database contains **100** records in the form of an array of objects, but I only need to get the first **10** records, not all **100**.

How do I correctly write a query to retrieve only **10** records?

Comment: depends on server side, you just make request at front end

Comment: You may want to include some code, just to show others what you're doing now.

Comment: What is your backend? Does it support a `page` request? Something like `/data?size=10`?

Comment: AngularJS is client side. Your backend should provide a query where you can specify how many elements desire to get

Answer (score 0):

You can take only first **10 records** in Angular at the Client side, just add below code.

Suppose you're getting 6 records, wanted to display only 3 then,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('sizeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = ["Audi", "BMW", "Dodge", "Fiat", "Ford", "Volvo"];
});
```

**in Html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="sizeCtrl">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in cars | limitTo : 3">{{x}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```